# UNION Two Tables AND calculate Column Merge

Tags: sql-server, union

I don't know if my wording for this question may be off, but here's the issue. I have to tables like the ones you see below. I Need to UNION the two tables, but divide Set1Count by Set2Count in the process. Please help.

---

(Note: I realize there may be another approach all together. Here are the details. Both tables have the exact same number of records - they are just built based on two different relationships. The result set must have the same number of records as the originals (not combine, but individually). Set1Count must be divided by Set2Count)

---

```
DECLARE @Set1 TABLE
    (
        Set1Count Int,
        Name varchar(50),
        [Month] Int,
        [Year] Int
    )

DECLARE @Set2 TABLE
    (
        Set2Count Int,
        Name varchar(50),
        [Month] Int,
        [Year] Int
    )


SELECT * FROM @Set1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM @Set2
```

Comment: Can you give an example of some data for Set1 and Set2 and what you would like the outcome to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this should do:

```
DECLARE @Set1 TABLE
    (
        Set1Count Int,
        Name varchar(50),
        [Month] Int,
        [Year] Int
    )

DECLARE @Set2 TABLE
    (
        Set2Count Int,
        Name varchar(50),
        [Month] Int,
        [Year] Int
    )


SELECT S1.[Name], S1.[Month], S1.Year, Set1Count/NULLIF(Set2Count,0) Div
FROM @Set1 S1
INNER JOIN @Set2 S2
ON S1.[Name] = S2.[Name] AND S1.[Month] = S2.[Month]
AND S1.[Year] = S2.[Year]
```

Note that this will work correctly if there are the same records on both tables, since I'm using an `INNER JOIN`. If that's not the case, then you should probably use a `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: I SWEAR I tried that same thing about 50 times and it didn't work - I think copy and pasted your select statement in and wabam! I must be having an off day. Many thanks fine sir :)

Comment: @wakurth - It happens to all of us ;-)

Answer (score 0):

change your first select to include a second column, `null as set2Count`, and change your second select to include another column in the first position, `null as set1Count`.  You'll need to decide how to join the sets before you can divide the values, though.  Are they joined on year and month?  Or maybe you don't need a union query at all, but to join them and then divide?

Comment: you are correct... I did not need a union at all. @Lamak's answer has a query that did the job. I had tried it before I asked the question (with an inner join) and it was duplicating records in odd ways... I must have been just staring at the screen for too long. Thank you for your feed back.